# Combine a bunch of PDFs converted from TIFF files as they're read in thru a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, tiff

I've got a Python web scraper that crawls thru a bunch of TIFF pages online and converts each to PDF but I can't figure out how to combine all the converted PDFs into one and write it to my computer.

```
import img2pdf, requests
outPDF = []

for pgNum in range(1,20):
    tiff = requests.get("http://url-to-tiff-file.com/page="+str(pgNum)).content
    pdf = img2pdf.convert(tiff)
    outPDF.append(pdf)

with open("file","wb") as f:
    f.write(''.join(outPDF))
```

I get the following error when I run it:

```
f.write(''.join(outPDF))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

**Update**

If you go to `http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/details_img.asp?doc_id=23543456&pg_num=1`, then open up a web dev console in your browser, you can see a `form` tag with a bunch of ".tif" URLs in a bunch of hidden `input` tags.

Comment: Did you try my code to download your PDF files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*img2pdf* has some quirkiness when it comes to converting TIFF and PNG files. The code solves some of the potential issues within your code, because it uses Pillow to reformat the image files for processing with *img2pdf*

```
import img2pdf
from PIL import Image

image_list = []
test_images = ['image_01.tiff', 'image_02.tiff', 'image_03.tiff']
for image in test_images:
   im = Image.open(f'{image}').convert('RGB')
   im.save(f'mod_{image}')
   image_list.append(f'mod_{image}')

with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
   letter = (img2pdf.in_to_pt(8.5), img2pdf.in_to_pt(11))
   layout = img2pdf.get_layout_fun(letter)
   f.write(img2pdf.convert(image_list, layout_fun=layout))
```

I modified your code to use my code above, but I cannot test it, because I don't know what website that you're querying.  So please let me know if something fails and I will troubleshoot it.

```
import img2pdf
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

outPDF = []

for pgNum in range(1,20):
   tiff = requests.get("http://url-to-tiff-file.com/page="+str(pgNum)).content
   im = Image.open(BytesIO(tiff).convert('RGB')
   im.save(tiff)
   outPDF.append(tiff)

with open("file.pdf","wb") as f:
   letter = (img2pdf.in_to_pt(8.5), img2pdf.in_to_pt(11))
   layout = img2pdf.get_layout_fun(letter)
   f.write(img2pdf.convert(outPDF, layout_fun=layout))
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

After you provided the actual URL for the target website, I determined that the best way to accomplish your task was to go another route. Based on your use case you wanted the PDF file that was being produced from all the hidden TIFF files. The source website will generate the PDF without downloading all those TIFF files.

Here is the code to get that generated PDF and download it to your system.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

download_directory = os.path.abspath('chrome_pdf_downloads')

prefs = {"download.default_directory": download_directory,
     "download.prompt_for_download": False,
     "download.directory_upgrade": True,
     "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

url_main = 'http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/details_img.asp? doc_id=23543456&pg_num=1'

driver.get(url_main)
WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='button' and @onclick='javascript:ValidateAndSubmit(this.form)']").submit()
```

If you still want to get the TIFF files, please let me know and I will look into downloading and processing them to produce the PDF file that the code above is obtaining.

Comment: on the line `im = Image.open(tiff).convert('RGB')`, I get this error: `ValueError: embedded null byte`

Comment: I added BytesIO to that line.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: Now it shows this error: `AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'convert'`. Maybe the URL has something to do with it. I'll update my question with specifics.

Comment: your url gives me - "image_from_file.asp" and not a tiff

Comment: Your url also gave me this - <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>

Comment: Updated my question once more.

Comment: Can you down this link as a TIFF file: image_from_file.asp?imageurl=\\ors_fs\ORImage\O\31833\O.31833.1637.0001.tif

Comment: How do you mean by "can you down this link?"

Comment: I cannot access the O.31833.1637.0001.tif using your code example.  But I understand what you are trying to do, but you are heading in the wrong direction.  There is an easier way to accomplish your task.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure how to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a multipage pdf out of multiple single pages PDFs?  I'm sure your use of join() is not correct.

Take a look at this tutorial. A couple years old but certainly still valid:

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/04/11/splitting-and-merging-pdfs-with-python/